# How do we calculate the input impedance of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, homework, input-impedance, inverting-amplifier

Question:

[image]

1.3
[image]

1.4
[image]

How would I calculate the input impedance in the diagrams above?

[image]

This is what I have tried in my exam, however I got this wrong, and my teacher had told me not to take into account the 2 10k resistors.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is homework-please tag it appropriately. What is your initial working/thinking on this?

Comment: You should make a distinction between **the input impedance of the opamp** (usually this is a very high impedance, see the datasheet of the opamp), and **the input impedance of the circuit** (which depends on the circuit **AND** the opamp). How the input impedance of **the circuits** you show are determined is described in many textbooks as these are **very common** circuits, the non-inverting and inverting amplifier configurations. So consult your textbook and see what you find.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a homework question, which is OK to ask about **but** you have to show what you have tried. You show nothing. The circuits you ask about are very common and with some searching you will find out how to determine their input impedances.

Comment: Your teacher is right. The 10k resistors don't have anything to do with input impedance.